# Cannot set Pins to LOW

Tags: programming, c++, motor, arduino-pro-mini

I am controlling 2 motors from my Arduino Pro Mini and L293D motor driver module. Problem is, I have to set a pin high and after 1 second set it to LOW. But that doesn't happen... The pin just stays HIGH and is never LOW.

Here's my Code -

```
    int IN2Left = 10;
    int E1 = 12;
    int E2 = 7;
    int IN3RevRight = 6;
    int trigPin1 = A0;
    int echoPin1 = A1;
    int distance1 = 0;
    int IN4Right = 5;
    int IN1RevLeft = 11;

    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(IN2Left, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(E1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(E2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(IN3RevRight, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(IN4Right, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(IN1RevLeft, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
      pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2Left, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4Right, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(IN4Right, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3RevRight,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(IN3RevRight, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4Right, HIGH);
  delay(1500);
  digitalWrite(IN2Left, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1RevLeft, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(IN1RevLeft, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2Left, HIGH);
  delay(100000);
    }
```

The `IN2Left` Pin never goes LOW... I am assuming a faulty Arduino but my Arduino seems to be working just fine as it runs other stuff (tested blink and reading an Ultrasonic sensor) just fine.

My deadline is 2 hours from now...

EDIT: Here's the complete void loop function... Note the two pins on top which go HIGH? They Never go LOW again in the entire code.

Comment: If you load a blank sketch, like `int main () { }` does the pin in question start off high?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something else connected to pin 10?

Comment: @NickGammon No... Its very strange..

Comment: @Gerben Too damn sure

Comment: I tried your amended code and the pin went low every 1 minute 40 seconds for half a second, which is what you told it to do. You have to watch closely to spot it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets it high, delays for 1000ms, sets it low, and then... turns around and sets it high almost immediately after. Try delaying in between.

Comment: Beaten by 24 seconds. :)

Comment: yeah it does... However, if the LOW command is in an if it never executes even when the if block runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
  digitalWrite(IN2Left, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(IN2Left, LOW);
```

It would go LOW for a few microseconds. Maybe put a delay after going LOW?

Comment: yeah it does... However, if the LOW command is in an `if` it never executes even when the if block runs...

Comment: @YaddyVirus Maybe you are trying to pull down something stronger than output driver. How about using LEDs with series resistors to confirm it (with everything else disconnected)?

Comment: *if the LOW command is in an if* - What are you talking about? There is no `if` in your code.

Comment: @NickGammon Actually I tried various ways of setting pins to LOW... One was to set a condition and accordingly set the pins to LOW.

Comment: Try: `void setup() { pinMode(10, OUTPUT); digitalWrite (10, LOW); } void loop () {}` - is pin 10 low then? If so, you can't say that pin 10 "never" goes low.